# Variable "i" not defined, but it was working at one point in time

Tags: excel, vba

I keep getting a variable not defined error for "i" in the code below. I notated the specific section of the code that is causing the issue with "THIS IS THE PROBLEM AREA". I only recently started having this issue. The thing is, the code was working, but then it started creating issues and now it has stopped functioning entirely.

I basically start with an excel file that has Columns A, B, C, D, E, F filled in with the content, then the first section of the VBA shifts it around to be a template format that the file has to be in to upload onto a database. Prior to the problem snippet:

- Column C shifts over to Column G
- Column D shifts over to Column K
- Column E shifts over to Column O
- Column F shifts over to Column S

At first, the code was working flawlessly. In fact, I took videos of it and showed it off to coworkers because I was so excited because it was the first code I wrote on my own (still learning). Sadly, one day it started to break where the problem snippet stopped counting the rows correctly, and was only inserting 1 and True for the first line and stopping after that. I tried the code a few more times and now it just is getting me the popup that says "variable not defined" for "i".

Anyone have any thoughts on why it has broken like this?

```
Sub Template_Setup()
'PLEASE READ IMPORTANT NOTE:
'IMPORTANT NOTE: ItemName must be Column_A and row 1, Content must be Column_Band row 1, AnswerA is Column_Cand row 1,AnswerB is Column_D and row 1, AnswerC is Column_E and row 1,AnswerD is Column_F and row 1
'No row 1 that contains labels for upload


Dim Col As String
Dim lastrow As Integer
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveSheet

'Column Insert Code
    Columns("C:E").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, _
      CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove 'or xlFormatFromRightOrBelow

    Columns("G:I").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, _
      CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove 'or xlFormatFromRightOrBelow
    
    Columns("K:M").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, _
      CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove 'or xlFormatFromRightOrBelow

    Columns("O:Q").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, _
      CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove 'or xlFormatFromRightOrBelow

    Columns("A:A").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, _
      CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove 'or xlFormatFromRightOrBelow

'
'Insert values before adding row 1

'Autofills of columns
Range("A1").Value = "RadioButton"
With Range("B:B")
    With Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
        .Offset(0, -1).FillDown
    End With
End With

Range("F1").Value = "Active"
With Range("C:C")
    With Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
        .Offset(0, 3).FillDown
    End With
End With

Range("L1").Value = "0"
With Range("K:K")
    With Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
        .Offset(0, 1).FillDown
    End With
End With

Range("T1").Value = "0"
With Range("S:S")
    With Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
        .Offset(0, 1).FillDown
    End With
End With

Range("H1").Value = "0"
With Range("G:G")
    With Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
        .Offset(0, 1).FillDown
    End With
End With

Range("P1").Value = "0"
With Range("O:O")
    With Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
        .Offset(0, 1).FillDown
    End With
End With

Range("J1").Value = "1"
With Range("G:G")
    With Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
        .Offset(0, 3).FillDown
    End With
End With


Range("N1").Value = "2"
With Range("K:K")
    With Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
        .Offset(0, 3).FillDown
    End With
End With

Range("R1").Value = "3"
With Range("O:O")
    With Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
        .Offset(0, 3).FillDown
    End With
End With


Range("V1").Value = "4"
With Range("S:S")
    With Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
        .Offset(0, 3).FillDown
    End With
End With

'Correct Answers Followed by 1's and True
'THIS IS THE PROBLEM AREA
For i = 1 To 4

    Select Case i
        Case 1
            Col = "G"
        Case 2
            Col = "K"
        Case 3
            Col = "O"
        Case 4
            Col = "S"
    End Select
    lastrow = Sheet1.Range(Col & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For r = 1 To lastrow
        If ws.Range(Col & r).Interior.Pattern <> xlNone Then
            ws.Range(Col & r).Offset(, 1).Value = 1
            ws.Range(Col & r).Offset(, 2).Value = "TRUE"
        End If
    Next
Next



'Insert 1 Row Above Row 1
'
    Rows(1).Insert Shift:=xlDown, _
      CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove 'or xlFormatFromRightOrBelow
'Insert Row1 Template headers
    Range("A1").Value = "ItemType"
    Range("B1").Value = "Name"
    Range("C1").Value = "Content"
    Range("D1").Value = "RightAnchor"
    Range("E1").Value = "IsRequired"
    Range("F1").Value = "ItemStatus"
    Range("G1").Value = "Answer"
    Range("H1").Value = "PointValue"
    Range("I1").Value = "Correct"
    Range("J1").Value = "ExportValue"
    Range("K1").Value = "Answer"
    Range("L1").Value = "PointValue"
    Range("M1").Value = "Correct"
    Range("N1").Value = "ExportValue"
    Range("O1").Value = "Answer"
    Range("P1").Value = "PointValue"
    Range("Q1").Value = "Correct"
    Range("R1").Value = "ExportValue"
    Range("S1").Value = "Answer"
    Range("T1").Value = "PointValue"
    Range("U1").Value = "Correct"
    Range("V1").Value = "ExportValue"
    Range("W1").Value = "MinValue"
    Range("X1").Value = "MaxValue"
    Range("Y1").Value = "StepValue"
    Range("Z1").Value = "InitialValue"
    Range("AA1").Value = "LeftAnchor"
    Range("AB1").Value = "SectionNav"
    Range("AC1").Value = "PageNav"
    Range("AD1").Value = "QuestionNo"
    Range("AE1").Value = "StartNo"
    Range("AF1").Value = "NoFormat"
    Range("AG1").Value = "AnswerFormat"


End Sub
```

Comment: Dim all your variables

Comment: Apparently you didn't have `Option Explicit`, and now you do. That is a good thing.

Answer (score 0):

At the top of your code, with the other declarations, add:

```
Dim i As Long
Dim r As Long
```

This is the meaning of @Tragamor's comment.

@GSerg's comment tells you why this has suddenly happened. You will find at the top of your module the words Option Explicit. It must have been added before the code stopped working.  It is good practice to always use Option Explicit, because it means that you *have* to declare (Dim) your variables, which can prevent unintended - and often very tricky to spot - errors.

Comment: Thank you all for answering this. I appreaciate the help greatly.  I did enable Option Explicit halfway through and did not know what it did! After experiencing this, I have finally started taking the time to really learn and understand VBA. I guess this issue I experienced finally motivated me.

Comment: @JosephFresco, cool :) Do feel free to Accept the answer :)